# Specify empty variable on make command line

Tags: command-line, makefile

I have some Makefiles that are flexible based on the existence of certain variables by using `ifdef` to check for them.  It is a bit annoying that I have to actually set the variable equal to something on the command line.  `make all DEBUG` does not trigger the `ifdef` but `make all DEBUG=1` does.  Perhaps I am just using the C pre-processor approach where it does not belong.

Q1) Is it possible to specify a variable on the command line to be empty?  Without even more characters?
Q2) What is the preferred approach for such boolean parameters to a make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MadScientist explained few minutes ago,

```
make all DEBUG
```

adds a target `DEBUG` to your make. Luckily, there is a workaround:

```
ifneq (,$(filter DEBUG,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
    DEBUG:=1 # or do whatever you want
    DEBUG: all; @echo -n
endif
```

It is essential to supply a dummy rule (e.g. echo nothing, as above) to the dummy target. And either put this statement at the bottom of your makefile, or specify the prerequisite target explicitly as in the example. Otherwise, `make` may wrongly choose **DEBUG** target  *instead* of **all**.

Note that this is not a preferred approach; the convention is like using `V=1` to turn echo on.

Another caveat is that `make` processes the command-line goals sequentially, e.g. `make A B` will first take care of **A** target, then of **B** target, whether these targets are independent, or depend one on the other. Therefore writing `make DEBUG PERFECT` and `make PERFECT DEBUG` could produce different results. But the order of parameters is irrelevant, therefore `make PERFECT=1 DEBUG=1` and `make DEBUG=1 PERFECT=1` are equivalent.

Comment: Points for creativity... but as you say, this would not be a preferred approach.  :]  Thanks.

Comment: You asked two questions, I answered both.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean `make all DEBUG=` here, right?  Without the `=` make will consider `DEBUG` to be a target to build, not a variable assignment.

The manual specifies that a variable that has a non-empty value causes `ifdef` to return true.  A variable that does not exist or exists but contains the empty string, causes `ifdef` to return false.  Note `ifdef` does not *expand* the variable, it just tests whether the variable has any value.

You can use the `$(origin ...)` function to test whether a variable is really not defined at all, or is defined but empty, like this:

```
ifeq ($(origin DEBUG),undefined)
  $(info Variable DEBUG is not defined)
else
  $(info Variable DEBUG is defined)
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

It is already clarified why you can't use just DEBUG. But I would like to add something.

You can use shell script before running **make** that setup all variables you need, so, for example in linux shell it will look like this:

```
$source debug_setup.sh
$make all
Make is starting...
Debug is enabled
...
```

where **debug_setup.sh** contains all environment variables you need to set up:

```
export DEBUG=1
export DEBUG_OPTION=some_option
```

This is nice since you can make comments there, you can comment out if you don't need something at the moment and would like to keep for the future, etc.

Then you can have several setup scripts that must/can be used as a part of standard routine. This all depends on how many variables you need to set up, how many sets of variables you would like to have, etc.

Note that it is a good idea to notify user somehow which set of variables is selected.